# KeyBoard error on boottime

Tags: keyboard, boot

When I Boot my computer boot screen says that there is an "KeyBoard error".But when my
computer started the KeyBoard is working properly.
And also when machine boot the three LED bulbs blink twice.
When error comes motherbord makes three beep sounds.
I dont think there is an error with my KeyBoard.What can I do to fix this...
Pls anyone help me.

OS:Windows 7

Processer:Intel Pentium DualCore

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. However, unless you want some help writing a program to get rid of the problem, the question is much more likely to get you help if you pose it on http://superuser.com instead, one of the many sister-sites of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

3 Beeps usually mean an memory error.

But at first you should look up the beep codes for your mainboard like the ones explained here: http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-010249.htm

Comment: Thnks for your guidence...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively its possible (depending on your hardware/BIOS config) that your BIOS is configured to expect a PS2 keyboard, and that you are using USB. In this case the Power On check might error, but the USB keyboard would work once you got into the operating system.

If this is the case you may be able to change the BIOS config to ignore errors when no PS2 keyboard is found.

The reason I suggest this is that I note that your machine is a dual core pentium, which is a few years old now, whereas the OS is windows 7. I'm guessing that you're not using the original OS/Peripherals for the PC.

Comment: But I dont think that dualcore processor will effect for this.Because Ram 2GB,hard 500Gb,vga 256 onboard.My Keyboard is not a USB one.In your opinion the os is not Gen__ine.Can you have any different answer & will it fix with a USB KeyBoard..

Comment: The only reason I mentioned "dualcore pentium" was because pentium is a little out of date now. Most newer machines would be at least Core 2 Duo, or even Core i3/i5/i7. Does your keyboard work if you are in the BIOS/ (can you get into the BIOS by hitting the relevant key during startup). Do you know what motherboard you're using?

Comment: I can manage Bios with my KeyBoard.There is no option to select the keyboard type in bios.This error occured after I Plug a new hard drive.But I dont think there is any combination with hard and keyboard.And also I reinstall Windows 7,But Same error occured!!!.